# how can I move up the DOM with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have very low jQuery knowledge so thats y I have a question..

I wonder if you can move some selector `div` with the help of jQuery.

Following is my current DOM

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="logo">
        ...
    </div> <!-- end .logo -->

    <div class="menu">
        ...
    </div> <!-- end .menu -->
</div>
```

but i want to move `.menu` div container to above than `.logo` div container like that

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="menu">
        ...
    </div> <!-- end .menu -->

    <div class="logo">
        ...
    </div> <!-- end .logo -->
</div>
```

is there a possible way to do this with the help of jQuery.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the jQuery documentation for DOM manipulation?

Comment: It's quite possible if you try first!!

Comment: `$('.logo').before('.menu')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a hundred ways to do this. Here's the one I just most readable:

```
$('.menu').insertBefore('.logo');
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7XaHb/)

Alternatively, if `.menu` should always be the first child of `.header` independently of `.logo`, you can use:

```
$('.menu').prependTo('.header');
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7XaHb/3/)

Comment: thank you mate.. i really appreciate. can help me a bit, can you please tell me what else jquery functions we can use for such task.

Comment: The [Manipulation methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/) API page has many documented methods for achieving similar DOM manipulation. `=]`